# Azure search - custom function for result boosting

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to move "complex" function to Azure Search. This function calculates score per each result element base on filter data (from search query) and data stored in result element. Score is use for reasult boosting. Base on my research Azure Search provides result boosting, but it's too simple for mine requirement.

Example function:

```
//filterElementsIds - ids taken from search query filter
public double Score(IEnumerable<string> filterElementsIds, ResultElement element)
{
    double score = 0;

    foreach(var elem in element.ScoreForFilters)
        if (filterElementsIds.Any(x => x == elem.Key))
            score += elem.Value * 1.5;

    return score;
}
```

Currently, I'm iterating through each result returned by Azure Search - calculating score and sorting elements inside my application.

Is it possible to implement such function in Azure Search to improve process of boosting results?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it appears like you are trying to boost the score of certain document if their key is equal to any of the IDs in your collection of "filterElements". If that's so, you could use the lucene query language to craft a query which does that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples

You could do a search that looks like this

OriginalSearchTerm OR (OriginalSearchTerm AND key:("filterID1" OR "filterID2" OR "filterID3"))

That way, documents that match both the original search term as well as having one of the filter ID as part of the "key" field will match higher than documents that only match the original search term. You can also term boosting to give a specific boost to the key field in this case
If that's so, could you use "term boosting" to achieve this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples#example-5-term-boosting

OriginalSearchTerm OR (OriginalSearchTerm AND key:("filterID1" OR "filterID2" OR "filterID3")^2)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. My only problem now is that weight for each key is stored in value (dictionary), so boosting query instead of ^2 should have ^value in this case.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. If you have access to the dictionary as you are constructing the query, you can replace the boost value to be something else dynamically. You just need to use boolean logic to restructure the query the way you want it. For example, maybe you could try:

OriginalSearchTerm OR ((OriginalSearchTerm AND key:"filterID1")^2 OR (OriginalSearchTerm AND key:"filterID2")^3 OR (...))

where 2 is the boost factor for id#1 and 3 is the boost factor for id#2.